Read hex of type data in SQL table to a file via powershell
Powershell 5.x.
M$ SQL Server 2019
An SQL table named "documents" contains a field file_data with type image . The sizes of bytes stored in file_data varies considerably but is rarely less that 30K.
I've crafted a PS script to read in data. I've swapped out the dataSet and foreach(row  idiom with using the $reader idiom . Some snippets of interest:
$SelectSqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, file_name, file_size, file_data FROM documents"
$SqlConnection.Open()
$reader = $SelectSqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

while( $reader.Read()) {
#   $sqlBytes = $reader.GetSqlBytes(0) doesnt work
    $doc_id   = $reader.GetValue(0)
    $doc_name = $reader.GetValue(1)
    $doc_size = $reader.GetValue(2)
    # now the fun part
    $buffer = New-Object -TypeName byte[] -ArgumentList $reader.GetBytes(3,0,$null,0,$document_file_size)
    $reader.GetBytes(3,0,$buffer,0,$document_file_size)

I would expect $buffer to contain $doc_size bytes from file_data
But this snippet complains of GetSqlBytes not liking 1 argument and GetBytes not liking 4 arguments. These came from other snippets on SO.
So it feels like I'm closer

Fyi the version of ssms (which is purely a UI) is irrelevant. The only version of interest is SQL server itself e.g. select @@version

Why do you think doc_data_try_1 gets populated incorrectly? maybe your data is 25 bytes big. Also, there's no such things as reading hex, hex is a display format. Unless your data stored strings in hex

SQL Server doesn't have a data type named data so what is it actually? The C# code suggests that it's storing binary data so possibly it's varbinary(max). Please Edit your question to include the DDL definition of the documents table.

The foreach loop seems incomplete, ar eyou dumping the variables within or outside the loop? If the latter then you will only get the last row.

Try : $b = [byte[]]::New(50)

Run the command SELECT id, file_name, file_size, DATALENGTH(file_data) AS file_data_length FROM documents in SSMS to check the length of the actual stored data. If that looks okay, pick one specific id value and run some tests against just that row.

You're using image? That's been deprecated since at least SQL Server 2005. Ref: ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL) Important The ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Additional benefits of using varbinary(max) instead of the deprecated image type is that you don't have to mess around with the associated TEXTPTR, READTEXT and WRITETEXT methods.

image data-type --- not up to me. Have to play the cards I'm dealt

You could change the data type of the column and literally no-one would notice. They are implicitly convertible between each other, and there is almost no functionality available for image that is not for varbinary
